# Water leaking from sink trap

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, dishwasher, smell, p-trap

This weekend I replaced a drain stopper and all the hardware down to the p-trap, keeping those parts original.

After connecting everything I ran the water for about 10-15 minutes while I cleaned up. There were no leaks. Later that night I looked under the sink and noticed a pretty large puddle. We left the home after my fix so I knew it wasn’t from us using the sink. We did however run the dishwasher. I noticed there was water on the compression nut that secured the stem to the p-trap. I tightened the nut.

Today there was no leaking all day until we ran the dishwasher again. It was considerably less, but still a leak. Again the water was popping around the compression nut. I tightened the nut some more.

Why would the dishwasher be causing my bathroom, clear on the other side of the house, to leak? Is that a sign of a clog somewhere  else in a line on the way out to the main?

Some other interesting things we’ve noticed about our plumbing that may or may not help diagnose this problem:

1. Whenever we start the dishwasher, a really foul smell comes up from the disposal.
2. We have a “if it’s yellow let it mellow” policy for flushing. A different bathroom (the kid’s) starts smelling really bad after it hasn’t been flushed. I know that sounds obvious but no other bathroom in the house has this problem.

Comment: Problem #2: You sure those boys can aim well? What are they eating/drinking? Some foods will have a _significant_ impact on the strength of smell of urine.

Comment: As to the leak: Are you sure you've got the nuts fully tightened? Is everything aligned nice and straight? Did you replace the washers? Compression fittings can take some misalignment (I know, I just redid our bathroom vanity and things didn't line up, but it's leak free), but the nuts have to be _tight_. Just hand tight (no tools), but tight, especially if not straight. Also, the washers can wear out or get damaged by tools when working or rough edges of freshly cut pipe.

Comment: Sounds like two unrelated issues to me.

Comment: @FreeMan ha! I know what you mean, but the reality is they use all 3 of our bathrooms (with equal amounts of poor aim) and theirs is the only one that generates that smell.

Comment: @FreeMan as for the leak, I ended up buying a completely new drain stopper/stem with new gaskets and flanges and washers and everything. the only thing "original" is the p-trap and the compression nut that attaches the stem to the p-trap. I originally had it hand tightened, but as the leaks have been coming with the dishwasher on, I've been using a wrench. I feel like I've been tightening it too much to be honest, but it's still leaking.

Comment: I'd suggest pulling it all apart and replacing the flange and washer on the one you've wrench-tightened. These are designed to seal with hand tightening only (granted, some have stronger hands than others), and if you've had to resort to a wrench then something is definitely wrong on the inside.

Comment: @FreeMan ok I'll look into that. last question: with plastic fittings, should I have pipe tape applied to all threads? perhaps that's contributing, because one section does not have it.

Comment: On compression fittings for a trap? Nope, I've never used _any_ thread tape. Having it _could_ be your problem. `</conversation>` _before the system starts yelling at us about chatting in comments._ ;)